# Удалить лишние html теги

Tags: php

Подскажите, как удалить при помощи php вложенные html-теги `strong`

Сейчас имеем такую строку:

```
<strong>
Жил старик со своею старухой <strong>У самого синего моря</strong> Они жили в ветхой землянке Ровно тридцать лет и три года.
</strong>
```

Нужно привести её к такому виду:

```
<strong>
Жил старик со своею старухой У самого синего моря Они жили в ветхой землянке Ровно тридцать лет и три года.
</strong>
```

Answer (score 3):

Организовать поиск строк между тегами `<strong>` и `</strong>`, а далее можно удалять либо все теги (*например, с помощью strip_tags()*), либо только необходимые `<strong>` и `</strong>`:

```
$str = '<strong>
Жил старик со своею старухой <strong>У самого синего моря</strong> Они жили в ветхой землянке Ровно тридцать лет и три года.
</strong>';

$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '~(?<=<strong>)(.+)(?=</strong>)~s',
    function($a) { return preg_replace('~</?strong>~', '', $a[0]); },
    $str
);

echo $str;
```

Результат:

```
<strong>
Жил старик со своею старухой У самого синего моря Они жили в ветхой землянке Ровно тридцать лет и три года.
</strong>
```

Comment: Неплохо, неплохо)

Answer (score 3):

Есть еще такой вариант

```
$text = "<strong>Жил старик со своею старухой <strong>У самого синего моря</strong> Они жили в ветхой землянке Ровно тридцать лет и три года.
</strong>";

// удаляет любые теги
$result = '<strong>'. preg_replace('/<(.*?)>|<\/(.*?)>/i', '', $text) .'</strong>';
echo $result;

// удаляет только теги <strong>
$result = '<strong>'. str_ireplace('<strong>', '', str_ireplace('</strong>', '', $text)) .'</strong>';
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант с использованием [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php):

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~<strong>\K(.+)(?=</strong>)~is', function($m) {
    return strip_tags($m[1]);
}, $string);
```